# Consume REST API using Guzzle 6

Tags: php, codeigniter, guzzle

I try to consume REST API using Guzzle 6. I read the documentation of Guzzle and I got way to consume REST API like below :

```
<?php

class Index extends CI_Controller {

    use GuzzleHttp\Client;

    $client = new Client([    
        'base_uri' => 'https://api.rajaongkir.com/basic/'
    ]); //LINE ERROR

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    function index() {
        // $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://api.rajaongkir.com/basic/']);
        $key = "b5231ee43b8ee75764bd6a289c4c576d";
        $response = $client->request('GET','province?key='.$key);
        $data['data'] = json_decode($response->getBody());
        $this->load->view('index', $data);
    }
}
```

If I declare variable **$client** in function index() there is no problem. I get the JSON and I success to show in my view.
I want just once declare *base uri* and *key* and I can use the *base uri* and *key* to all function I have.

So I try to declare variable that contains *base uri* and *key* as global variable. But I got error in line **$client**. The error is :

> syntax error, unexpected '$client' (T_VARIABLE), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST)

How to fix it? What wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not write any code directly in class definition.
You need to define class variable (field) and create instance of class in constructor, eg:

```
class Index extends CI_Controller {

    use GuzzleHttp\Client;
    protected $client;

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->client = new Client([    
            'base_uri' => 'https://api.rajaongkir.com/basic/'
        ]); //LINE ERROR
    }

    function index() {
        // $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://api.rajaongkir.com/basic/']);
        $key = "b5231ee43b8ee75764bd6a289c4c576d";
        $response = $client->request('GET','province?key='.$key);
        $data['data'] = json_decode($response->getBody());
        $this->load->view('index', $data);
    }
}
```